# What are the differences between Meteor Developer organization members, and package maintainers?

Tags: meteor, atmosphere.js, meteor-packages

Meteor packages can be published and updated by [maintainers](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteoradd), or by Meteor Developer organization members. What are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 1):

A Meteor Develop Organization member can publish and update any package under that organization's namespace. For example, if `dandv` is a member of the `webix` organization, they can publish `webix:foo` and `webix:bar`. Organization membership is managed via [Your Organizations](https://www.meteor.com/account-settings/organizations) after you log into http://meteor.com.

A maintainer is given access to update an existing package, using the `meteor admin maintainers` command:

```
$meteor help admin maintainers            
Usage: meteor admin maintainers <package name> [--list]                         
       meteor admin maintainers <package name> --add <username>                 
       meteor admin maintainers <package name> --remove <username>              

Without options (or with --list), list the users and organizations that are     
maintainers for a particular package.                                           

With --add, add an authorized maintainer to a package. Use this to give your    
collaborators the ability to work with your packages.                           

With --remove, remove an authorized maintainer from a package. You cannot remove
yourself if you are the last maintainer on a package.                           

You can only add or remove one maintainer at a time.                            

Options:                                                                        
  --add         add an authorized maintainer                                    
  --remove      remove an authorized maintainer                                 
  --list        list authorized maintainers (the default)
```